# Key Binding to reschedule agenda item after 2 hours

Tags: org-mode, init-file

---

below is my function for reschedule agenda item to "today + 3 days

```
(defun my/org-agenda-reschedule-week () 
    (interactive) 
    (org-agenda-schedule nil "+3d"))
```

---

similarly i want function for rescheduling agenda item after current time + 3 hours, these code doesn't work

```
(defun my/org-agenda-reschedule-hour () 
    (interactive) 
    (org-agenda-schedule nil "+3h"))
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do what you want:

```
(defun my/org-agenda-reschedule-hour () 
  (interactive) 
  (org-agenda-date-later-hours 3))
```

You can then bind it with:

```
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map "x" 'my/org-agenda-reschedule-hour)
```

Where `x` is whatever key you want. If you want to create more similar functions, there is also `org-agenda-date-later-minutes`, as well as `earlier` versions for both this and the `hours` function. Similarly, you can use `(org-agenda-date-later n)` to shift by `n` days

Comment: That solved my problem, 
i am also surprised that this function "org-agenda-date-later-hours" has not been mentioned in Org Mode PDF Manual. 

where can i find such functions, if i put "M-x apropos-command org-agenda" then would it list all functions for org agenda ?

Comment: @nirag, unfortunately, I don't  think these functions are documented in the org manual. The way that I learned about the functions was by looking through the org-mode source code, and reading the documentation for the individual functions in the source. You can get to the source with `M-x find-library org-agenda`. Of course, if you already know the name of the function you are interested in, you can use `C-h f` and then the name of your function, and you will get the documentation with a link to the source.